# Can we obtain stronger estimates in Bombieri-Vinogradov Theorem with moduli restricted to scarce sets of order $\log{\log{x}}?$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The [Bombieri-Vinogradov Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombieri%E2%80%93Vinogradov_theorem) states that given $A>0$, there exists $B>0$ such that for $Q=\sqrt{x}\left(\log x\right)^{-B},$  we have $$\sum_{q\leq Q}\max_{y\leq x}\max_{\begin{array}{c}
a\text{ mod q}\\
(a,q)=1
\end{array}}\left|\pi(y;q,a)-\frac{y}{\phi(q)\log y}\right|\ll \frac{x}{(\log x)^A}.$$

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136887/the-bombieri-vinogradov-theorem-restricted-to-moduli-divisible-by-k?rq=1) it was asked what happens when we restrict $q$ so that they are all divisible by some smaller integer $k.$

I was wondering if we can obtain a stronger bound if we restrict $q$ such that $q\in S$ for some small set $S$ (say $|S|=O(\log \log x)$). Normally, applying [Siegel-Walfisz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Walfisz_theorem) to such small sets $S$ consisting of numbers at most $(\log x)^c$ for some $c>0$ would give bounds similar to Bombieri-Vinogradov Theorem but one wonders if Bombieri-Vinogradov Theorem applied to scarce sets gives better error terms?

Comment: No, probably not. When you average, you want to average over more things, not less things. If you average over too few things, then it is not clear how to take advantage of the averaging.